# IAR compiler, renaming .rodata section

Tags: linker, pragma, iar

I am using the IAR Embedded Workbench, consider the following C-example

```
#pragma default_function_attributes = @"MY_APP";

void func()
{
  printf ("this is a test" );
}
```

Using the section name "MY_APP" in the .icf file of the linker, the code of the function func() can be located to a specific memory address. But the C-compiler puts the read-only data "this is a test" into the section '.rodata' only (together with all other '.rodata' sections of other modules).

Is there a similar #pragma, to rename the .rodata section of the c-module ? I want to locate the read-only data after the code data of the related module.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no `#pragma` to place the read-only data of a module in a specific section, but there are other ways to accomplish what you are trying to do.

The easiest way is to define a block in the linker configuration file (`.icf`) containing all code and data from the given module and the place this block in a region. A stripped example is shown below:

```
define memory mem with size = 4G;
define region CODE_region = mem:[from 0x8034 to 0x100000000 - 1];
define block MyApp with alignment = 8 { ro object myapp.o }
"MyApp": place in CODE_region { block MyApp }
```